# Difference between with ; and without ; in expression of awk command

Tags: awk

I have a question about awk , The command :

`awk 'NR!=1 {print $0}' FILENAME` and `awk 'NR!=1;{print $0}' FILENAME` would yield different result.

I would like to know what's difference with `;` and without `;` in the expression.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An awk program is a sequence of pattern/action pairs.  The program

```
awk 'NR!=1 {print $0}'
```

executes the command `{print $0}` for any record for which `NR!=1` is true, but

```
awk 'NR!=1;{print $0}'
```

has 2 pattern action pairs.  The first is `NR!=1` with the default action (since no action is specified).  The default action is to print, so that pair prints all records but the first.  The second pattern/action pair has no pattern, so it always executes, printing every record.

Perhaps it helps to re-write the second as:

```
awk 'NR!=1{print}
1{print $0}'
```

to make the two pattern/action pairs explicit.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation ,the code you write at the end of your answer , awk 'NR!=1{print} 1{print $0}' , Does 1 between {print} and {print $0}' impact anything ? Or it's just for clarification, Thanks

Comment: @Pro_gram_mer It does not have any effect. It evaluates true for every record, so the action is always executed.

Comment: OK,understood,THANKS!